# Getting a datetime object from strptime

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to write a script that formats the date in a log file. The log file is meant to be read by excel after the conversion.

```
import datetime

def excel_date(date1):
    temp = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30)
    delta = date1 - temp
    return float(delta.days) + (float(delta.seconds) / 86400)

data=open(".\input.log").read()
file_ = open('output.log', 'w')


for row in data.split('\n'):
    prefix = row[:1]
    sdate = row[1:29]
    suffix = row[30:]

    offset = datetime.timedelta(0)
    dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(sdate, '%a %b %d %H:%M:%S.%f %Y') + offset

    excelDate = excel_date(dt)

    file_.write(dt.strftime('%d.%m.%Y %H:%M:%S') + "\t" + excelDate + "\t"+ suffix + "\n")

file_.close()
```

The problem occurs when I try to use the excel_date function. I know that strptime returns a string and that the function expects a datetime object. Is there a way of creating a datetime object from strptime or converting the string into one?

Thanks

Comment: I am not sure if I misunderstood something, but regarding your question 'Is there a way of creating a datetime object from strptime' -> strptime actually returns such an object. See the documentation for it: https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime

Comment: Oh! thanks.The culprit was  temp = dt.datetime(1899, 12, 30). When I changed it to temp = datetime.datetime(1899, 12, 30) it worked.